# How to extract common scss code from multiple files?

Tags: sass, dry

After converting a lot of redundant crappy css files into scss files, I have a bunch of scss files. I'm pretty sure there is a lot of common css repeated among these files and I would like to extract this code.

As an example, let's say I have this block of scss code (let's call it block A) :

```
.test {
    color: white;

    .toto {
        background: red;
        font-size: 12px;
    }
}
```

And another block (that we'll call block B) :

```
.test {
    color: black;

    .toto {
        background: blue;
        font-size: 12px;
        text-align: center;
    }
}
```

I want to be able to extract the following common scss code from block A and B :

```
.test {
    .toto {
        font-size: 12px;
    }
}
```

It seems like a simple task to do, but with a large list of long scss files, it's really painful to do it manually. After searching for a while I didn't find any tool for that.

An intermediary solution could be to convert sass code to a multi-dimensionnal associative array and to process arrays to find intersections, but I could not find any simple solution to do that either, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you want to maintain only the properties that are equal or delete those that are repeated?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few approaches but in this instance, I would opt for a variable:

```
$base-font-size: 12px;

.test {
    color: white;

    .toto {
        background: red;
        font-size: $base-font-size;
    }
}

.test {
    color: black;

    .toto {
        background: blue;
        font-size: $base-font-size;
        text-align: center;
    }
}
```

Or you could add a toto mixin with some defaults and use that:

```
@mixin toto($background: red, $text-align: left, $font-size: 12px) {
    .toto {
        background: $background;
        text-align: $text-align;
        font-size: $font-size;
    }
}


.test {
    color: white;
    @include toto();
}

.test {
    color: black;
    @include toto(blue, center);
}
```

EDIT: or use extend:

```
.font-size-12 {
    font-size: 12px;
}

.test {
    color: white;

    .toto {
        @extend .font-size-12;
        background: red;
    }
}

.test {
    color: black;

    .toto {
        @extend .font-size-12;
        background: blue;
        text-align: center;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but what I need is not a way to rewrite this code by hand, but more like a script reading a list of files and giving me the common rules found in all of thoses files. Something like "extract-scss-intersection --output=intersection.scss file1.scss file2.scss ... fileN.scss" which would parse file1 to fileN and output intersection.scss

Comment: Well you could load them into a PHP script or whatever you're comfortable and turn them into arrays - you could then remove elements with matching keys and rewrite the files... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6205017/parse-a-string-of-css-declarations-and-convert-it-to-an-array

Comment: That's the idea indeed, which means I need to find a working Sass parser, or to implement one (but this sounds like a tricky task). If you know a good one, able to convert a sass file into a PHP multidimensional array, please let me know :)